# Proof by induction of the Inequality of Harmonic numbers: $H_{2^n} \ge 1+ \frac n2$

Tags: proof-writing, induction, harmonic-numbers

My question is, for the question below, in the inductive step, where does $\dfrac{1}{2^{(k+1)}}$ come from?And where does $2^k$ come from in the third last step?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the $1/2^{k+1}$ comes in because that's what the $2^{k+1}$-th term would be (they want to prove the inequality for $H_{2^{k+1}}$). The $2^k$ on the third to last line comes in by them saying that 
$$\frac{1}{2^k+1}+\frac{1}{2^k+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\ge \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}.$$
Going from $2^k+1$ to $2^{k+1}$, there are $2^k$ terms.  And so the right hand side of the inequality (i.e. the third line from the bottom) simplifies to $2^k\cdot\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are
$2^k$ terms,
each at least $\frac1{2^{k+1}}$.

These terms are
$\frac1{2^k+1}$,
$\frac1{2^k+2}$,
$\frac1{2^k+3}$,
...,
$\frac1{2^{k}+2^k}=\frac1{2^{k+1}}$.